# inefficient to efficient way to create subfolder in FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I was using Make directory to create a folders and subfolder in my ftp (using filezilla) works fine,but when i try to do in my test server (IIS FTP) doesn't work ,throws 550,file not found or no access.so just a quick way to change the code to create subdirctory in my ftp server works fine but i know its a kinda shitty way to do like that.

Changed my code based on @Markus

```
        var dir = new ConsoleApplication5.Program();
        string path = "ftp://1.1.1.1/testsvr01/times/" + "testfile" + "/svr01fileName";
        string[] pathsplit = path.ToString().Split('/');
        string Firstpath = pathsplit[0] + "/" + pathsplit[1] + "/" + pathsplit[2] + "/" + pathsplit[3] + "/";
        string SecondPath = Firstpath + "/" + pathsplit[4] + "/";
        string ThirdPath = SecondPath + "/" + pathsplit[5] + "/";
        string[] paths = { Firstpath, SecondPath, ThirdPath };
        foreach (string pat in paths)
        {
           bool result= dir.EnsureDirectoryExists(pat);

            if (result==true)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {   //create dir
                dir.createdir(pat);
            }
        }
        upload(path,filename);

    }
    private bool EnsureDirectoryExists(string pat)
    {

        try
        {
            //call the method the first path is exist ?
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pat);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sh", "se");
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return false; }

    }
    public void createdir(string pat)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest createdir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(pat));
            createdir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            createdir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sh", "se");
            createdir.UsePassive = true;
            createdir.UseBinary = true;
            createdir.KeepAlive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response1 = (FtpWebResponse)createdir.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream1 = response1.GetResponseStream();
            ftpStream1.Close();
            response1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

Please if any of you guys find a better way,suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of code for ensuring a directory exists. Is there a Directory.Exists() method (or a similar method you could leverage)? Then you could call an EnsureDirectoryExists() before uploading.

```cs
private bool EnsureDirectoryExists(string path)
{
    // check if it exists
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
        return true;

    string parentPath = GetParentPath(path);
    if (parentPath == null)
        return false;

    bool result = EnsureDirectoryExists(parentPath);

    if (result)
    {
        CreateDirectory(path);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Disclaimer: You might need to tweak the logic a bit and use the FTP functions, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: ,thanks for the suggestion ,unfortunate i can't create directory the way you mention.Even ftp.makedirectory is two line code to create the whole directory but if you want to create in IIS FTP then it wont allow you to do in a single line code,you have to create each directory one by one.

Comment: I am creating each directory one by one (so starting to create the parent directory). And yes, it might be 2 lines of code where I have only one, but I believe it's still simpler than to go through the try/catch blocks you proposed.

Comment: ,true, i will reduce a hell amount of code just pass the path to create one by one.Thanks again for your help.